# SPIP: From Tag directly to an article

Tags: php, html, mysql, spip

I work with SPIP and a plugin who called tagsphere who works fine with the tags in SPIP. I have a tag groupe where i put only one article for a tag.
Now when i click on a tag in tagsphere he send me before to a menu where i can see all articles who are linked with this tag. But i want that he send me directly to the article without to see the tag menu before.

Here the code from the model of thagsphere:

```
            <div id="tagsphere-#ENV{id_article}"> 
                <ul>
                <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>                 
                    <li>[<a href="#URL_MOT">(#TITRE)</a>]</li>  
                </BOUCLE_mot>   

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the tag page, you have to link directly to the article. The `<B_article>` block prevents display the tag if no article is linked.

```
<div id="tagsphere-#ENV{id_article}"> 
    <ul>
        <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>  
            <B_article>
            <li>
                <a<BOUCLE_article(ARTICLES){id_mot = #ID_MOT}{0, 1}> href="#URL_ARTICLE"</BOUCLE_article>>
                #TITRE
                </a>
            </li>  
            </B_article>
        </BOUCLE_mot>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your help and sorry that i answered so late. I have tested your code and now i see only used tags in my cloud. But how can i skipped the tag page to go directly to the article?

Comment: Not sur if I understand well :
- On the first page, you have a list of tags (those contained in a specific group, with one tag/one article). This list displays the name of tags.
- When you click on a tag, you don't many to display the tag's page, but the article linked to the tag.

Is it right ?

Comment: Also I think I did a "typo" with `<a href="#URL_MOT">` and I edited the post with `<a href="#URL_ARTICLE">`, maybe that solve the problem.

Comment: Hello 
i have tested your code and now he takes me well directly to the article. It is perfect. Thank you very much. I have also another question who is similary. I make a new question and i hope that you can help me. Thanks and best wishes

Comment: Hi adhumi
if you can help me with this problem in SPIP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658276/if-query-for-tags-in-spip
THX & cheers

Comment: Your welcome, do not hesitate to ping me on twitter if you have troubles with SPIP :-)