# If query for tags in SPIP

Tags: php, html, mysql, spip

It is possible to create an IF query for the tag in SPIP?
When i have only one article linked to the tag than he take me directly to the article. But if i have more than 1 article, than he does taken me to the tag page of spip, where are the listing of the linked article.

Here the code to go directly to the article

```
<div id="tagsphere-#ENV{id_article}"> 
    <ul>
        <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>  
            <B_article>
            <li>
                <a<BOUCLE_article(ARTICLES){id_mot = #ID_MOT}{0, 1}> href="#URL_ARTICLE"</BOUCLE_article>>
                    #TITRE
                </a>
            </li>  
            </B_article>
        </BOUCLE_mot>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here the code to go to the tag menu

```
<div id="tagsphere-#ENV{id_article}"> 
    <ul>
        <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>                 
            <li>[<a href="#URL_MOT">(#TITRE)</a>]</li>  
        </BOUCLE_mot>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, will work with any SPIP version.

```
    <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>
[(#REM) Link to mot]  
        <BOUCLE_check(ARTICLES) {id_mot} {1,1}>
            <li><a  href="#_mot:URL_MOT">#_mot:TITRE</a></li>
            [(#ID_ARTICLE|oui)]
        </BOUCLE_check>
[(#REM) Link to one article]
            <BOUCLE_one(ARTICLES) {id_mot} {0,1}>
                <li><a  href="#URL_ARTICLE">#_mot:TITRE</a></li>
            </BOUCLE_one>               
        <//BOUCLE_check>
    </BOUCLE_mot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional display is a real lack in SPIP. This is what I would do (don't have any SPIP environment with me to check).

```
<div id="tagsphere-#ENV{id_article}"> 
    <ul>
        <BOUCLE_mot(MOTS){id_groupe ?}>

            <BOUCLE_articles(ARTICLES){id_mot = #ID_MOT}>
                <B_article_unique>
                <li>
                    <a<BOUCLE_article_unique(ARTICLES){id_article}{si #TOTAL_BOUCLE|==1}> href="#URL_ARTICLE"</BOUCLE_article_multiple>>
                        #TITRE
                    </a>
                </li>  
                </B_article_unique>

                <BOUCLE_article_multiple(ARTICLES){id_article}{si #TOTAL_BOUCLE|!=1} />
                <li>
                    <a href="#URL_MOT">
                        #TITRE
                    </a>
                </li>  
                </B_article_muliple>
            </BOUCLE_articles>

        </BOUCLE_mot>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi adhumi, i have changed _{si #TOTAL_BOUCLE|==1}>_  with   _|?{#TOTAL_BOUCLE|==1}>_   because he doesn't know for the criterion  _si_ for both and after he told me that he doesn't know **TOTAL_BOUCLE** for both line. Do you know why?

Comment: Here i send you two images with the errors [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img829/3348/wvl7.png)
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img850/4975/yyyw.png)

Comment: Which version of SPIP are you using ? `{si` is only available with SPIP 3.0+ (if you don't use 3.0+ and don't have a good reason for it, I strongly recommend to switch !)

Comment: Hi, it is SPIP 2.1.8. The problem is, i can't switch the version, because there are some plugins using doesn't working with version 3. Also there are very much contents and it will take much time to test if all works well with version 3. another idea?